# Most efficient way to implement a function to run after web content is loaded in Android?

Tags: android, webview

So i have a program that loads an image and a quote of text from a remote server in a background thread. i have a countdown that after 10 seconds loads a new image and a new quote from the remote server. However, when a connection is slow content is sometimes loaded halfway through the countdown, so i am looking for a way to start the countdown only after the content have been loaded.

From my searching i have found webView.setWebViewClient as a what seems to be a way of doing this by placing the timer.start in the onPageFinished method.

i believe i had a hard time phrasing my question to return a useful solution to my problem, so i am asking here hoping someone more knowledgeable could help me find if the webView method is the way to go, or if there is a more efficient way of solving my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered yourself :) In case you are loading the content into the WebView, overriding onPageFinished method of WebViewClient is the way to go.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webview.reload();
            }
        }, 10 * 1000);
    }
});
```